# AngularJs Routing With Json response instead of Html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It seems AngularJS routing is depend upon the html template on response. Is it possible to use AngularJS routing in conjunction with JSON response and bind this JSON with $scope.

Comment: Erm, I think its the other way around - Response HTML Template is based on the AngularJS routing. Can you be more specific on the changes you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @callmekatootie, I have paging enabled which I need to update the url using angularjs but my response data from server is json instead of html.